# Get VB.NET Relative \Upload path to the running application?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I found my trouble spot I think may be only because I am running the app on localhost, but I dont feel I can safely deploy to the next tier to test.

I have a Telerik RadAsyncUpload control that has a `TargetFolder="\Upload"` and was assuming all along it would use the \Upload folder in the application.

Is there a way to force the path to be *inside* the application?

```
lsFullFileName = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(fuUploadFile.TargetFolder) 
                 + "\" + Path.GetFileName(lsFileName)
```

This is in VB.net. and the file is ending up in "C:\Upload" (which I created to see what was going on) but the file should be moved from its temp location in App_Data to
 "C:\applicationName\applicationName\Upload"

ASPX

```
<telerik:RadAsyncUpload 
    runat="server"
    ID="fuUploadFile"
    MaxFileSize="262144000" 
    OnClientFileUploaded="OnClientFileUploaded" 
    InputSize="50"
    TargetFolder="\Upload" 
    AllowedFileExtensions=".wav,.mp3,.mpeg,.mpg,.wmv,.avi,.mp4">
</telerik:RadAsyncUpload>
```

Thanks.

Comment: It is usually a very bad idea to let users upload files inside your webroot. You should leave it as is (outside your application) and create a handler to get the file back. That way you can secure access to your files and many more (like logging when file was acessed and so on) and you're sure no one will execute anything on your server from a remote origin...

Comment: @Bartdude Where is this "very bad idea" coming from? If the permissions on the Upload folder inside the application are set properly then there will be no issue i.e. no one has execute permission. I find it more concerning that a service account has the ability to create folders outside of its domain. However, there is some truth to the fact that if the upload folder is outside of the publicly available site there is less to worry about, but it should not be left as is on a random folder on the root of the system drive. Maybe move it to one level above the web root "C:\applicationname\Upload".

Comment: @Tim > Obviously it shouldn't be a random folder, but if I'm not mistaken html or javascript files wouldn't be impacted by the "execute" permission, meaning that someone could "host" malicious javascript onto your domain and through that get access to possibly a lot of (user) data. The fact is that it is a known best practice to store user uploaded files outside webroot even though you should also sanitize input, put proper access rights on folders etc... you never know what could happen, better be careful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're insistent on keeping your upload directory within your site folders, then you can use a path like `~\Upload` which will force the path to start from the web application root.

However, this is generally a bad idea as Bartdude outlined.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
uploadPath As String = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "Upload"
```